# Missing a web part in Site collection features after deploying it succesfully

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom web part that I have developed in VS 2010 and tested on the dev and works great.  I found /bin/debug folder where all the web part files are located. Now i took just the .wsp file and copied to the production leaving the other files on Dev. Then i added the solution and then deployed it but when i go to the site collection features in production I couldn't find the deployed web part. Can anyone know how to truobleshoot this issue ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the web part to the site. You should be able to see the web part in Site Settings -> Galleries-> Web Parts -> New. and be then able to add it in the gallery.